# Why can't Ditto copy eyes properly?

Tags: pokemon, pokemon-detective-pikachu

In *Pokémon: Detective Pikachu* (2019), Ditto can copy things perfectly, so why can't it copy eyes properly?

[image: Ditto with incorrectly copied eyes]

Comment: Game Freak developers Junichi Masuda and Ken Sugimori revealed that Ditto was originally based on the iconic smiley face. Its eyes and mouth are exactly like ":)", which is an emoticon representing the smiley.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In the [anime episode where Ditto debuted](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP037) it was just the specific Ditto that the party encountered that couldn't mimic faces correctly: that was the plot of the episode and by the end the Ditto had overcome the disability. However, [the look became iconic](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Duplica%27s_Ditto#Trivia) and a good visual shorthand for "this is a transformed Ditto", so it stuck.

Comment: The Ditto in the movie was also experimented on, so it's also not necessarily a good example of what a normal Ditto would be capable of.

Comment: From what I've seen in the anime, I think normal Dittos are only able to copy other Pokemon, not people. Zorua/Zoroark can though.

Comment: This [wiki page](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Duplica%27s_Ditto#Trivia) does say the same thing.

Answer (score 30):

[Shapeshifters not being able to change their eyes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EyesAreMental) is a common trope, possibly as a reflection of the old sentiment that eyes are windows to the soul, and in part because it's an easy storytelling mechanism to occasionally indicate to the viewer that it's the shapeshifter while leaving it mildly plausible that the character manages to hide this behind sunglasses, tipped hats, claims of contact lenses, etc.